# rename of file extension doesnt work

Tags: shell, filenames, variable-substitution

I'm using code like the following to create a logfile using the shell's string manipulation tools: I have a file name and, in the case of an error, I need to create a log file with the err.

Suppose the `$fileName` is `test.tmp`:

```
echo ' l_error_msg' >> $UPLOAD/output/$fileName.err
```

This creates a file named `test.tmp.err`.

Hence I tried the code below to create `test.err`:

```
echo ' l_error_msg' >> $UPLOAD/output/${$fileName%.*}.err
```

But this does not work.

Comment: i) Questions should only have a single question. I removed your second question, please post a new question about that.

Comment: You have an additional `$` in there: `${$fileName%.*}.err` Remove the one after the opening brace.

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work". What happens? (Or doesn't happen?) Do you get any error messages? (What are they?)

Answer (score 1):

Given a variable `foo="bar.baz"`, the correct syntax to remove `.baz` is `${foo%.*}`:

```
$ foo="bar.baz"
$ echo ${foo%.*}
bar
```

Remove the extra `$` and it should work as expected:

```
$ fileName="test.tmp"
$ echo ${fileName%.*}.err 
test.err
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
echo ' l_error_msg' >> $UPLOAD/output/`echo $fileName|awk -F. '{print $1}'`.err
```